# Node-red-start doesn't start, instead loops on fetching update

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, node-red

After updating npm and nodejs using the guide on 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9a_ztJqaII

which is basically:

```
sudo rpi-update

sudo shutdown -r now

sudo apt-get -y update

sudo apt-get -y upgrade

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo shutdown -r now

bash <(curl sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-red/raspbian-deb
package/master/resources/update-nodejs-and-nodered)
```

whenever I type node-red-start, It says Node-RED is not yet fully installed Fetching Node-RED update. 
Asks to update I say yes, **then after updates finishes I try to start-node-red it still says Node-RED is not yet fully installed. 
Seems like a loop**. Any help??
I am using raspberry pi3, with the latest raspbian image.
my npm -v is 5.6.0
node -v is 8.11.1
but previously it was 9.11.1 
[raspbain oS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP6P1.jpg)

other related links and threads for this issue I found:-

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-red/sDtp-pXlvnM

https://github.com/node-red/raspbian-deb-package/issues/7

Comment: You installed node-red natives modules with a different version of node. Try reinstalling node-red.